# How do I use 'cgn' for word under cursor?

Tags: search, replace

I really like and often use the <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> command for replacing something I was currently searching for, but it sort of lacks a (imho) rather intuitive feature: replace the word (or whatever) under the cursor. My current approach is to search for the word in question, but that feels like a hack, plus the cursor immediately moves onwards to the *next* hit.

Is there any way to use <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> on the *current* word?

Comment: I feel your pain !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do it (as an option), as far as I know.

I have the following mapping:

```
" change current word (like ciw) but repeatable with dot . for the same next
" word
nnoremap <silent> c<Tab> :let @/=expand('<cword>')<cr>cgn
```

Basically what it does is:

1. make current search term == word under cursor (without actual search and jump)
2. call `cgn` -- and it will use current search from 1.)

For reference:

- `:h @/`
- `:h <cword>`

Comment: Instead of `:let @/=expand('<cword>')<cr>` can't you simply use  `*` or `#`  in normal mode to search for the word under the cursor, and then use `cgn`? [`:h star`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#star)

Comment: @statox I can, but the cursor will jump to the next occurrence of the word

Comment: Oh right I use a mapping to avoid the cursor to jump, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 8):

### Make `*` stay at the cursor position

```
nnoremap * m`:keepjumps normal! *``<cr>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256697/vim-search-and-highlight-but-do-not-jump

### Plugins for `*`: [vim-asterisk](https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-asterisk), [vim-slash](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-slash), ...

There are quite a few (lightweight) plugins which try to enhance searching in vim with the star command.

Typically, people miss that the star command does not consider a visual selection and secondly, what you want, to not move the cursor when pressing `*`.

After installation of one of these, you would press `*cgn` to achieve what you want.

In case of `vim-asterisk`, you have to override the builtin `*` yourself in your vimrc. `vim-asterisk` suggests:

```
map *   <Plug>(asterisk-*)
map #   <Plug>(asterisk-#)
map g*  <Plug>(asterisk-g*)
map g#  <Plug>(asterisk-g#)
map z*  <Plug>(asterisk-z*)
map gz* <Plug>(asterisk-gz*)
map z#  <Plug>(asterisk-z#)
map gz# <Plug>(asterisk-gz#)
```

where `z*` means stay. However, you can make `*` to stay with

```
map *  <Plug>(asterisk-z*)
map #  <Plug>(asterisk-z#)
map g* <Plug>(asterisk-gz*)
map g# <Plug>(asterisk-gz#)
```

vim-slash does this for you. This might be a reason to prefer vim-asterisk because you have control of what gets remapped.

There are more of them. Just to give you an idea I mention a few:

- [vim-evanesco](https://github.com/pgdouyon/vim-evanesco)
- [SearchHighlighting](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) ([github](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SearchHighlighting))
- [vim-visualstar](https://github.com/thinca/vim-visualstar/blob/master/doc/visualstar.txt#L105-L107)

### Plugin with new operator: [sad.vim](https://github.com/hauleth/sad.vim)

If you like an explicit mapping for this operation, consider https://github.com/hauleth/sad.vim. This remaps `s` (changes builtin and clashes with a few other plugins, e.g. vim-sneak and vim-sandwich). `siw` and then press `.` as often you want to repeat the change for the next search matches.